# Problems with function QTimer::singleShot

Tags: qt, qtimer

I am trying to record sound by QAudioInput. According to the doc in this website [QAudioInput](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaudioinput.html/). But when I ran, it exported an empty-raw file. After checking, It seems like the function QTimer::singleShot didn't working ( I added statement `qWarning << "Done"` in `void stopRecording()` and It didn't display "Done" so I thought it had some mistake in QTimer::singleShot function ).

This is my code used to check function QTimer::singleShot

```
----Check.pro----
QT += core
QT -= gui
TARGET = Check
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
HEADERS += test.h

-----test.h------
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <iostream>
#include <QObject>
#include <test.h>
#include <QDebug>

using namespace std;

class Object: public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
private slots:
  void func() { cout << "Hello"; }
};

#endif // TEST_H

----main.cpp----
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <iostream>
#include <QObject>
#include <test.h>
#include <QDebug>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Object *o = new Object;
    QTimer::singleShot(10000, o, SLOT(func()));
    return 0;
}
```

And this code doesn't working, too. Can anyone explain me? I am newbie at Qt-programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program exits right after it's set the timer - it has no time to fire.

For the timer to work, you need an event loop running. Without the event loop, no events get processed.

Change the last line of your `main` to

```
return a.exec();
```

Also change your test slot by adding `<< std::endl` or flush `std::cout` otherwise you might see no output on the console.

Your program should then work as expected (except it won't ever finish since nothing will cause the event loop to stop - just interrupt it).

Comment: Oh, I got it. So I have to create a event loop to make for that function works? Thank you :D